# Completely remove horizontal space between plots

Tags: python, matplotlib

- I want to reduce the space between these three subplots :

```
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1,3, figsize = (20,8), subplot_kw={"projection": ccrs.EuroPP()} , dpi = 300)
    axes[0].add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
    axes[0].coastlines(resolution='10m', lw=0.5)
    for name, group in imp_1_days.groupby(['drivers'] , sort = False):
        axes[0].scatter(group['Longitude'], group['Latitude'], 
                        c=group['color']
                        , alpha=0.75, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree() , edgecolor = "black")      

       
    axes[1].add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
    axes[1].coastlines(resolution='10m', lw=0.5)
    for name, group in imp_7_days.groupby(['drivers'] , sort = False):
        axes[1].scatter(group['Longitude'], group['Latitude'], 
                        c=group['color']
                        , alpha=0.75, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree() , edgecolor = "black")      
      
    axes[2].add_feature(cartopy.feature.BORDERS, linestyle='-', alpha=0.5)
    axes[2].coastlines(resolution='10m', lw=0.5)
    for name, group in imp_30_days.groupby(['drivers'] , sort = False):
         axes[2].scatter(group['Longitude'], group['Latitude'], 
                        c=group['color']
                        , alpha=0.75, transform=ccrs.PlateCarree() , edgecolor = "black")      

    plt.show()
```

- Current result :

[image]

- I have tried :

```
constrained_layout=True
plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0 , wspace = 0)
plt.tight_layout()
axes.set_aspect('equal')
```

But there is still some space left between the plots.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you try `fig.subplots_adjust` **after** setting the axes aspect? Disregard `tight_layout` entirely, it's just something that works like `subplots_adjust` with automatically chosen arguments so you not use both.

Comment: Your plots have a set aspect ratio so if your figure aspect ratio is wide there will be white space somewhere.  Make your figure narrower.

Comment: Matplotlib 3.6.0 also has layout=‘compress’ that is meant for this situation.